# Why is compareDF not rendering html output?

Tags: r

I want to get the html output as shown at this link: https://rpubs.com/alexsanjoseph/compareDF_intro. I am using the following code, but when I run the last line to print the html output, I get "NULL" output. What am I missing here?

```
library(compareDF); library(tidyverse); library(htmlTable)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Division,  ~Student, ~Maths, ~Physics, ~Chem, ~Discipline, ~PE, ~Art,
        "A",   "Isaac",     90,       84,    91,         "B", "B",   34,
        "A",  "Akshay",     85,       92,    91,         "B", "B",   36,
        "A", "Vishwas",     93,       93,    92,         "A", "B",   21,
        "A",   "Rohit",     95,       92,    71,         "C", "B",   37,
        "A",    "Venu",     99,       92,    82,         "A", "E",   78,
        "A",  "Ananth",     99,       81,    91,         "B", "A",   24,
        "B",    "Jojy",     67,       92,    81,         "B", "A",   27,
        "B",   "Bulla",     84,       73,    81,         "C", "A",   68,
        "B",   "Katti",     90,       95,    99,         "C", "B",   49,
        "B", "Dhakkan",     78,       96,    71,         "C", "C",   39,
        "B",   "Macho",     90,       82,    81,        "A+", "D",   30,
        "B",  "Mugger",     95,       71,    94,         "A", "C",   26
  )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Division,  ~Student, ~Maths, ~Physics, ~Chem, ~Discipline, ~PE, ~Art,
        "A",   "Isaac",     90,       84,    91,         "A", "B",   34,
        "A",  "Akshay",     85,       92,    91,         "A", "B",   36,
        "A", "Vishwas",     82,       93,    92,         "B", "B",   21,
        "A",   "Rohit",     94,       92,    71,         "D", "B",   37,
        "A",    "Venu",    100,       92,    82,         "A", "E",   78,
        "A",  "Ananth",     78,       81,    91,         "B", "A",   24,
        "B",    "Jojy",     99,       92,    81,         "B", "A",   27,
        "B",   "Bulla",     97,       73,    81,         "C", "A",   68,
        "B",   "Katti",     78,       95,    99,         "C", "B",   49,
        "B",   "Rohit",     79,       96,    71,         "C", "C",   39,
        "B",   "Macho",     90,       82,    81,        "A+", "D",   30,
        "B",  "Vikram",     99,       79,    98,         "A", "B",   99,
        "B", "DIkChik",     91,       71,    84,         "E", "C",   99
  )


ctable_student = compare_df(df1, df2, c("Student"))

print(ctable_student$html_output)
```

Also, can you suggest other R packages that compare multiple dataframes?

Comment: Do you need `htmlTable::htmlTable(ctable_student$comparison_df)` ?

Comment: I need the colored html output shown at  https://rpubs.com/alexsanjoseph/compareDF_intro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `create_output_table` function

```
compareDF::create_output_table(ctable_student)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, automatically opening up a Web browser and displaying the output:

```
ctable_student <- compare_df(df1, df2, c("Student"))
library(htmlTable)
htmlTableWidget(ctable_student$html_output)
```