# html_output giving me a NULL response when I try and make a table

Tags: html, r

I tried to make a table using

```
print(hba1c_diff$html_output)
```

but I keep getting a `NULL` response and I have HTMLtable package installed. I want to compare missing/changed data from my two data sets (`HBA1C_S` & `HBA1C_Q`) and show the differences in an HTML table. This output works all the way until I try and print out the HTML table.

```
library(compareDF)
hba1c_diff = compare_df(HBA1C_Q,HBA1C_S,c("pid"))
hba1c_diff$comparison_df

hba1c_diff$comparison_table_diff

hba1c_diff$change_count

print(hba1c_diff$html_output)
```

Why do I keep getting the `NULL` response?

Comment: This doesn’t solve your problem but note that calling `print` explicitly is usually (always?) unnecessary. `print` is called implicitly when executing an expression on the R command line. In scripts, you’d generally use other functions to generate explicit output. In a similar vein, calling `c(…)` on single values is unnecessary; the function’s purpose is to combine *multiple* values.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60090201/why-is-comparedf-not-rendering-html-output

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks